# rails, general understanding of URIs and controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, anchor

i have a Message model and controller. and in it, i have the standard functions such as index, show etc.

when i go to "localhost:3000/messages", my index.html.erb gets displayed, which in turn renders my partial _messages.html.erb.

and in there, i have an anchor href

```
<a href= "received_messages">Received Messages</a>
```

however, i encounter 2 issues.

received_messages isn't being appending the URL, which i thought it would normally do unless i added a / in the beginning. how do i make it append?

and also.. if i manually type in "localhost:3000/messages/received_messages", i keep getting redirected to the messages#show function. why is that in general?

i have a received_messages.html.erb and even in my routes, i have

```
match '/received_messages', to: 'messages#received_messages'
```

which i have the function #received_messages in my controller as well.

why does it keep getting redirected to messages#show

thanks a lot = )

Comment: What happens when you type localhost:3000/received_messages

Comment: Routing in Rails is one of those things that isn't going to just click with one little example. Given how important routing is, you really need a thorough understanding of it. Start [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and you will be way ahead of the game.

Comment: thanks! i read your link and it was very helpful = )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked:

> if i manually type in "localhost:3000/messages/received_messages", i
>   keep getting redirected to the messages#show function. why is that in
>   general?

In general, you have the idea of "messages"... and to

1. view the collection of messages, you'll go to "/messages"
2. To view a specific message (with id 56) , you'll go to "/messages/56"
3. To edit, "/messages/56/edit"
4. To create a new one: "/messages/new"

So, when you go to /messages/received_messages, the system, is attempting to show the message with id "received_messages"

If you want an action on the Collection of messages, you can setup your routes like:

```
resources :messages do
  collection do
    get :received
  end
end
```

This will match up "/messages/received", and run the MessagesController#received action, and render the app/views/messages/received.html.erb file.

Comment: thanks! the collection was what i needed! i decided to read the rails guide for routes for more info = )